# Testing angular controller: when to create new scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

When testing an angular controller, is it not always necessary to create a new scope by calling $rootScope.new()?

Here is my controller:

```
myControllers.controller("myCtrl1", ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.todos = [{"name": "Learn Angular"}, {"name": "Install Karma"}];
$scope.date = '1/1/2014';   
}]);
```

And here is my passing test:

```
describe("controllers", function() {
    var $scope, $rootScope, $controller;    

beforeEach(function() {
    module("myApp.controllers");        
}); 

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {     
    $controller = _$controller_;    
    //scope = $rootScope.new() **When would you do this?**
}));

//Basic Controller
it("sets todos on scope", function() {
    var scope = {}; //**Creating an empty scope object**
    $controller("myCtrl1", {$scope : scope});
    expect(scope.todos.length).toBe(3);
});
});
```

I was under the assumption that I need to create a new clean scope every time I test a controller but apparently I was wrong as the above test passes. Any explanations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In your case it is passing because your controller is only assigning values to the scope, so it can be any object. But for example if the controller had to listen to an event then the test would fail.

```
$scope.$on('datachange', function(event, args) {
  // do something
})
```

In that case you would have to create a new scope to make your test pass.

Comment: In general, I simply just create a new scope and call it a day. They're cheap, and you don't end up having to refactor lots of code when you decide to switch your implementation around. That being said, great answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not using any `$scope`'s methods, like `$on` or `$watch` or whatever. Also, to trigger watches in a test, you quite often need to use `$scope.$digest()`. None of those will work if you pass an empty object as a scope to a controller, of course.

Depends on situation.